# UITableView inside UIScrollView partially invisible in Xcode 7.0.1?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiscrollview

So I was working on an update to an Objective-C app coded with Xcode 6 but this time with Xcode 7.0.1 (and recently with Xcode 7.1) and I spotted a strange outcome with a specific part of my code.
First, I have to state that in the previous version of the app this part of the code was working just fine. So we are talking about a UIScrollView that contains a bunch of things among those we can find three UITableViews displaying three top lists.

Here's the problem : since working on Xcode 7.0.1 the UITableViews aren't displaying any infos anymore, but I wasn't able to find out why since the infos of each cells are actually here when you select one....

Has anyone encounter the same problem ?

Here is the code :

```
- (void)toppassionglob:(NSString *)topglobreceived {

//on retransforme le string des stats en data
NSData *toppassioner = [topglobreceived dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSError *error3;
NSArray *jsonArray3 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:toppassioner options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error3];
if (jsonArray3) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        //on purge notre tableau
        [toppassion removeAllObjects];

        //puis on traite les infos
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray3.count; i++)
        {
            NSDictionary *jsonElement = jsonArray3[i];

            Games *newpassionner = [[Games alloc] init];
            newpassionner.name = jsonElement[@"pseudo"];
            newpassionner.score = jsonElement[@"nbvote"];
            newpassionner.image = jsonElement[@"nbvotesoffline"];

            [toppassion addObject:newpassionner];

        }

        //puis le remplissage des tops
        [_toppassionnerglob reloadData];

    });
}
```

That's for the call of infos (it works)

And then inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath: function :

```
RankCell *myCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RankCell"];

if (myCell == nil) {
    myCell = [[RankCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
}

    Games *thisone = [toppassion objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    myCell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)indexPath.row+1];
    myCell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    myCell.name.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", thisone.name];
    myCell.rank.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ votes, %@ offline", [self separateur:thisone.score], [self separateur:thisone.image]];

}
```

Thanks for your answers in advance.

EDIT:
Here are what toplobreceived and jsonArray3 contains

topglobreceived = (__NSCFString *)@"[{\"pseudo\":\"Padadise\",\"nbvote\":\"7969\",\"nbvotesoffline\":\"364\"},{\"pseudo\":\"Roope\",\"nbvote\":\"5647\",\"nbvotesoffline\":\"0\"},{\"pseudo\":\"Spank78\",\"nbvote\":\"2696\",\"nbvotesoffline\":\"6\"},{\"pseudo\":\"All Ice\",\"nbvote\":\"680\",\"nbvotesoffline\":\"73\"},{\"pseudo\":\"NewPad\",\"nbvote\":\"73\",\"nbvotesoffline\":\"1\"},{\"pseudo\":\"Nell\",\"nbvote\":\"47\",\"nbvotesoffline\":\"0\"},{\"pseudo\":\"AppleFriend\",\"nbvote\":\"4\",\"nbvotesoffline\":\"0\"}]"

jsonArray3  = (__NSCFArray *)   @"7 objects"
[0] __NSCFDictionary *  3 key/value pairs

[0] struct __lldb_autogen_nspair
key NSTaggedPointerString * @"pseudo"
value   NSTaggedPointerString * @"Padadise"

[1] struct __lldb_autogen_nspair
key NSTaggedPointerString * @"nbvote"
value   NSTaggedPointerString * @"7969"

[2] struct __lldb_autogen_nspair
key __NSCFString *  @"nbvotesoffline"
value   NSTaggedPointerString * @"364"

for jsonArray3 I give only the first object (not to be redondant)

Comment: Please post some codes and images please.

Comment: Sure. I have edited the question.

Comment: I can't post images (restriction) for the moment...

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. Can you log the value of  `topglobreceived` and `jsonArray3`?

Comment: Sure. It's done.
And like you say, my problem is precisely that nothing looks wrong...(it was working perfectly in previous version and nothing has been touched)

Comment: Don't see what is wrong here... Do you try to change the background color  of the cell, the table view, the label, ... ?

Comment: I did. The problem seems to persist, since when we change the background we can see some sort of white box that comes before the cell. That is until you select one cell because as you do the cell displays correctly with all infos (only the cell is highlighted)

Also I was able to reproduce the wrong outcome in a new project basically empty (it only asks for the infos and have the set up "UIScrollView then UITableView inside").

Comment: "we can see some sort of white box that comes before the cell"? Mean the labels are here? Right? Let try to change color of the text of the label.

Comment: The labels are here indeed, we can see them (only) when we select a cell. Changing their properties does nothing to the issue. The changes are working but they are visible only if the cell is selected, otherwise they are invisible......I'm sure it would be much easier to understand with pictures, but I can't post some (yet), sorry

Comment: So weird. Do you try with other devices, other ios. ....

Comment: Same outcome on every simulated device of Xcode 7.1 (the app is Universal)....

Comment: OMG !! I have it ! I figured it out ! Thank you so much anhtu, you made me persist on property tests ! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out !

In newer versions of Xcode, the initial properties of the cells (not the elements you design in your custom cell) have changed. One in particular is the background of the textfield of the cell that is now white as default or is placed in front of the custom elements of the dynamic cell.

To solve my problem I had to had this bit of code and everything worked as it should.

```
    myCell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

That wasn't easy to find out...